# FormsModule Not Working Properly in Different Module Than App Module

Tags: angular, angular-forms

i have FormsModule present in SharedModule..

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports : [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModuleModule { }
```

and this sharedModule is imported in every module.
But Forms module doesnt work.

it gives error -

```
No directive found with exportAs 'ngForm'.
```

But when i import this module(where sharedModule is imported) in my app.module.ts, FormsModule start working.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { LoginModule } from './login/login.module'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: can you please include the module that gives you the error message?

Comment: @PMO1948
 This is the module in which shared module is imported

`code` import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModuleModule } from './../shared-module.module';

import { LoginpageComponent } from './loginpage/loginpage.component';
import { FirstredirectComponent } from './firstredirect/firstredirect.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginpageComponent, FirstredirectComponent],
  imports: [
    SharedModuleModule
  ]
})
export class LoginModule { }

Answer (score 3):

You are exporting modules that you have not imported in your shared module,

Amend your shared module to

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule
  ],
  exports : [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModuleModule { }
```

Comment: I tried this approach but i am still getting same error.

My main concern is if its mandatory to import a feature module in the root module(app.module.ts)? even if no selector or component is being used directly

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

1. Use angular 13.2.0
2. Use nx workspace
3. Setting path in tsconfig.json
4. Export NgForm from SharedModule (Not import in SharedModule, just export)

Then I have the same issue.
If I import error module (LoginModule) in app.module.ts (just import in typescript file), can solve the problem too.

I Found the problem is import statement in my router.module.ts

1. Import by relative path will cause "ngForm not found"
   ex: import {LoginComponent} from "./modules/login/components/login/login.component";
2. Import by relative path with index.ts still cause "ngForm not found"
   ex: import {LoginComponent} from "./modules/login";
3. Import by tsconfig path still cause "ngForm not found"
   ex: import {LoginComponent} from "@cms-ng-modules/login/components/login/login.component";
4. Import by tsconfig path with index.ts will... solve the problem
   ex: import {LoginComponent} from "@cms-ng-modules/login";

I solve the problem, but I don't know why...